# Python efficient reverse list JSON serialisation

Tags: python, json

I was looking for an efficient way to serialise a python list in a reversed order.

I tried to do `json.dumps(reversed(mylist))` but apparently `json.dumps`does not accept iterators.

I can also do `json.dumps(list(reversed(mylist)))` but that is terribly inefficient with very large lists, and I do not need the temporary list created, I was hoping to serialise the list on the fly instead of creating temporary list.

I think I can use `json.JSONEncoder` for that, but I do not really get what should I return from the `default` function.

I also have to stick with standard library because I do not have freedom to install other packages.

So far I tried the two proposed solutions and here is the test output:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('li.reverse(); json.dumps(li)', number=1, globals=globals())
2.5034537549945526
>>> timeit.timeit('"[{}]".format(",".join(map(json.dumps,reversed(li))))', number=1, globals=globals())
41.076039729989134
```

I am still thinking that implementing my own `JSONEncoder` would be more efficient, but I still do not exactly know how to do it.

Comment: Is in place reversing the list first using `mylist.reverse()` (avoids the copy) - do your serialization, then reverse it again if needs be?

Comment: It is better than creating a new list, but it still it creates an intermediate step that is not needed. But thanks for the hint. :)

Comment: Having had a look through the json library - it's not quite as simple as it seems. The JSONDecoder.default has a bit that says *For example, to support arbitrary iterators, you could*... but that suggests you then return a list from that iterable which makes sense for subiterables (eg if you had `{test: range(10)}` expanded... but not for the entire `reverse` of your data. It's further complicated by the fact that some levels are handled by the C implementation and other bits by `_functions` with nested `_functions`... For sheer simplicity I'm sticking with `list.reverse` :)

Comment: `json.dumps(mylist[::-1])` is another way of doing this, but duplicates the list.

Answer (score 6):

One way to avoid a copy is to reverse the list inplace, eg:

```
mylist.reverse()
json_string = json.dumps(mylist)
```

Then `mylist.reverse()` it back if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

Before we go crazy, see if any of the following meet your performance requirements:

```
mylist.reverse(); json.dumps(mylist); mylist.reverse()
json.dumps(mylist[::-1])
json.dumps(tuple(reversed(mylist)))
```

You mentioned defining your own JSONEncoder default function, which is fairly simple to do (example at the very bottom*), but I don't think it works here since the json.JSONEncoder requires the default function to convert the object into one of the following:

```
None, True, False, str, int, float, list, tuple, dict
```

Converting an iterator to a list or tuple would create a large object, which is what we're trying to avoid.

You'll either need to modify your json library or monkey-patch it.

Here's the CPython source code of json.encoder. PyPy, Jython, and other Python implementations are probably using the same code for the json module.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/json/encoder.py#L204

```
def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,
    _key_separator, _item_separator, _sort_keys, _skipkeys, _one_shot,
    ## HACK: hand-optimized bytecode; turn globals into locals
    ValueError=ValueError,
    dict=dict,
    float=float,
    id=id,
    int=int,
    isinstance=isinstance,
    list=list,
    str=str,
    tuple=tuple,
    _intstr=int.__str__,
    ...
    def _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            yield _encoder(o)
        ...
        elif isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
            yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)

        # Add support for processing iterators
        elif isinstance(o, iterator_types):
            # Side-effect: this will consume the iterator.
            # This is probably why it's not included in the official json module
            # We could use itertools.tee to be able to iterate over
            # the original iterator while still having an unconsumed iterator
            # but this would require updating all references to the original
            # iterator with the new unconsumed iterator.
            # The side effect may be unavoidable.
            yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_index_level)
```

For performance reasons, you'll want to define the iterator types outside of the function and bring it in as a local.

```
str_iterator   = type(iter( str()    ))
list_iterator  = type(iter( list()   ))
tuple_iterator = type(iter( tuple()  ))
range_iterator = type(iter( range(0) ))
list_reverseiterator = type(reversed( list()  )) 
reverseiterator      = type(reversed( tuple() )) #same as <class 'reversed'>

# Add any other iterator classes that you need here, plus any container data types that json doesn't support (sets, frozensets, bytes, bytearray, array.array, numpy.array)
iterator_types = (str_iterator, list_iterator, tuple_iterator, range_iterator,
                  list_reverseiterator, reversed)
```

If you want to go the monkey-patching route, you'll need to redefine the json.encoder._make_iterencode function, replacing all occurrences of `isinstance(X, (list, tuple))` with `isinstance(X, (list, tuple)+iterator_types)`

```
import json
def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,
        _key_separator, _item_separator, _sort_keys, _skipkeys, _one_shot,
         iterable_types=_get_iterable_types(),
         ...
    ):
    ...

json.encoder._make_iterencode = _make_iterencode
```

These changes look something like this: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/3034/files

*As promised, how to define your own default function, though not useful for dumping iterators without copying the iterator into a list or tuple first.

```
class JSONEncoderThatSupportsIterators(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        try:
            iterable = iter(o)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        else:
            return list(iterable)
        # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

li = range(10000000) # or xrange if Python 2
dumped = JSONEncoderThatSupportsIterators().encode(reversed(li))
assert dumped.startswith('[999999, 999998, 999997, ')
assert dumped.endswith('6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]')
```

Alternatively, rather than subclassing `json.JSONEncoder`, you can define the `default(self, o)` function and pass it as an argument to `json.dumps(default=default)`.